# Repairing a control board for an automatic gate opener, it has a faulty trimpot 100k 906k

Tags: replacement, trimpots

[image]

FAAC control board 12 V has a faulty trimmer (single turn rotary carbon). I could not find the exact values in a replacement part. Can I use one with the values 705 100k? It is used to adjust the opening/closing time. The original values are 100k 906k.

Comment: Would you provide more information for your FAAC control board?

Comment: Please add a photo of the board and failed component!

Comment: I suspect that the resistor value is 100 K.  The other numbers may be a date code or manufacturer's model number.  Any 100 K pot that will fit the board should work.

Comment: The low voltage (12} board has 4 separate trimmers for adjusting, torque, pause, open/close time, and leaf delay. It controls two sweep arms 220v. The O/C timer determines the distance for the gate swing. Fully open and shut. I am ignorant when it comes to electronics, so I can't tell you what all it entails. The problem that I had was that after the initial setup, it would work fine for a while, but then it would lose its setting. seemed to be weather related,(humidity?) labeled 100k 906k Piher Spain rotary through hole single turn carbon. The closest replacement I could find was the 705 100k

Comment: On one of the sales sites, someone referred to the numbers without an id. such as 102 sometimes meant 10 plus 2 zeros IE. 1000K ohms? Does that sound right?

Comment: FAAC 540 control bd.